# Как правильно создать связь многие ко многим между двумя таблицами?

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть две таблицы между которыми нужно создать связь многие ко многим:

```
CREATE TABLE my_contacts
(
  contact_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  last_name VARCHAR(30),
  first_name VARCHAR(20),
  email VARCHAR(50),
  gender CHAR(1),
  birthday DATE,
  PRIMARY KEY (contact_id)
);

CREATE TABLE interests
(
  int_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  interest VARCHAR(20),
  PRIMARY KEY (int_id)
);
```

Для организации связи многие ко многим нужно создать дополнительную таблицу:

```
CREATE TABLE contact_interest 
(
  contact_id INT NOT NULL,
  int_id INT NOT NULL
);
```

Как правильно создать все связи в дополнительной таблице? Нужно сделать, чтобы два столбца, из которых состоит дополнительная таблица, были составным первичным ключом, а также внешними ключами.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обе таблицы сделайте с `ENGINE=InnoDB` потому как только этот движок поддерживает внешние ключи.

```
CREATE TABLE contact_interest 
(
  contact_id INT NOT NULL,
  int_id INT NOT NULL,
  primary key (contact_id, int_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (contact_id) 
        REFERENCES my_contacts(contact_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (int_id) 
        REFERENCES interests(int_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

В `FOREIGN KEY` можете добавить `ON DELETE CASCADE` если хотите что бы из этой таблицы автоматически удалялись записи в случае удаления записи из родительской таблицы.

Comment: Почему в описании таблицы никак не отображается, что столбец является и первичным ключом и внешним?

Comment: @jisecayeyo  потому что по синтаксису это не требуется. Описываются отдельными предложениями все внешние ключи и составной первичный ключ. А какие столбцы вошли в ключи видно и какое нибудь средство отрисовки базы на основе этой информации конечно на рисунке пометит рядом со столбцом что он входит в какие либо ключи

Comment: Еще такой вопросик. В задании ограничения внешниго ключа может использоваться слово `CONSTRAINT`. Для чего оно предназначено?

Comment: @jisecayeyo В MySQL оно нужно что бы задать имя ограничения `constraint key_NAME foreign key ...` Если его нет, то назначается некое дефолтное имя. Зная точно имя можно потом писать скрипты на удаление ограничения: `alter table table_name drop foreign key key_NAME`. И оно нужно для совместимости, в других диалектах SQL (например в oracle) ключевое слово constraint является обязательным