# Игра со значениями полей MySQL

Tags: mysql

Добрый день. 
Есть таблица  vehicles_char_of_vehicles (vehicle_id - FK, charact_id - FK, value).
Как сделать так, чтобы неможно было (допустим по ошибке) однинаковые значения:
1 - авто, 1 - грузоподъемность, 2000 - знаечние и вторая запись 1, 1, 3000.
Через unique поле я просто сделаю так, что одну характеристику можно будет ввести всего один раз, например, для первого грузовика в char_id - 1, value - 2000, а запись char_id - 1, value - 3000 - для второго грузовика уже будет ошибка, так как cgar_id - unique. Как достичь того, что мне надо?

Comment: Сделайте уникальный ключ на два поля, вероятно.

Comment: Вы пишите все непонятнее и не понятнее. лишь из далека можно догадаться о чем речь. Вы можете включить оба поля _id в primary key (никто не обязывает его делать из одного поля). Либо если PK есть и он реально используется (есть ссылки на него), вы можете сделать уникальный индекс из этих двух полей `create unique index NAME on Table(v_id, c_id)`

Comment: так какой путь следует выбрать в ДАННОМ СЛУЧАЕ: таблица vehicles (id - PK), characteristics (id - PK), vehicles_char_of_vehicles (vehicle_id - FK (vehicles.id), char_id - FK (characteristics(id)), value)?

Comment: @Visman, объясните,пожалуйста. Ведь поля vehicle_id, char_id ужеявляются внешними ключами, значит я не могу сделать их PK или что вы имелы в виду?

Comment: Никто не мешает включать поля FK в PK

Comment: @Mike, раз Вы уже мучаетесь со мной - напишите на моем примере как эти id, являющиеся FK сделать одновременно и PK. И разве не приведет это к тому, что комбинация не можно будет дляодной и той же машине написать разные характеристики, к примеру, машина 1, харкт.1 и машина 1- характеристика 2. Характеристики не повторяються, но id машины - уже был, а он PK - значит ошибка

Comment: PK из обоих полей, значит уникальна будет именно комбинация машина-характеристика. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/546703/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BC%D1%8F-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8/546717#546717

Comment: @Mike, все теперь все понятно. Спасибо. К стати, вопрос с автопредприятием уже решил вродедодумался, как организовать структуру. Искренне Вам благодарен за все Ваши коменты и ответы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Два уникальных ключа на два поля.

Comment: то есть два PK? но ведь не может же поле быть и PK и FK одновременно?

Comment: спасибо,уже объяснили