# Добавления новости c несколько категориями

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Мне нужно сделать форму добавления новости в ней должно быть функция присваивание нескольких категорий, например статья Названия1 входить до категории: Категория1 и Категория2. 
Вопрос как правильно организовать БД, я сделал так :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

пример записи в news_categories:

```
1;id_Названия1;id_Категория1;
2;id_Названия1;id_Категория2;
```

Если так правильно проектировать БД, то как правильно добавлять новости через запрос новость, выходить что нам нужно наперед знать id дабаляемой новости

Comment: В общем то верно. Хотя в news_categories поле id не нужно. Достаточно двух полей FK и primary key включающий оба эти поля. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/546703

Comment: А по поводу добавления новости ... вы же наверняка пишите новость и одновременно с ней категории. так что делаем insert into news, после чего получаем `last_insert_id()` и с этим id уже вставляем записи в таблицу категорий